# Joining 2 SQL Servers seem to be slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with joining 2 servers together.
At first, I created a linked server by using sp_addlinkedserver [10.51.16.222]. 
Then I query using this command below.

```
 SELECT   drawing.CustomerPN
FROM [10.51.16.222].ascomlogistics.dbo.sale_detail INNER JOIN
[10.51.16.222].ascomlogistics.dbo.wipqtysale ON sale_detail.WQSID = wipqtysale.ID INNER JOIN
[10.51.16.222].ascomlogistics.dbo.wip ON wipqtysale.WID = wip.ID INNER JOIN
[10.51.16.222].ascomlogistics.dbo.drawing ON wip.DID = drawing.ID INNER JOIN
[AscomSPC].[dbo].[log_RunSerial]  ON sale_detail.Sd_Serial =log_RunSerial.WorkSerial
WHERE (AscomSPC.dbo.log_RunSerial.DateTime BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-05')   AND AscomSPC.dbo.log_RunSerial.Final = '0' AND CustomerPN!='' GROUP BY drawing.CustomerPN
```

This command take 13 seconds.
I was so curious how long it is if i query only second server(10.51.16.222) by using following command.

```
select  drawing.CustomerPN
FROM [10.51.16.222].ascomlogistics.dbo.sale_detail INNER JOIN
[10.51.16.222].ascomlogistics.dbo.wipqtysale ON sale_detail.WQSID = wipqtysale.ID INNER JOIN
[10.51.16.222].ascomlogistics.dbo.wip ON wipqtysale.WID = wip.ID INNER JOIN
[10.51.16.222].ascomlogistics.dbo.drawing ON wip.DID = drawing.ID 
 GROUP BY drawing.CustomerPN
```

This command take only 1-2 seconds. That makes me confused so much why joining 2 SQL Servers is slow but if i query only the second server seem to be normal.
I have tried using index and store procedure , that is a bit better but still be slow.

Does anyone have any idea to solve this problem?

Sorry for my bad English. I do it my best.

Thank you in advance for the answers

Comment: Because it's cross-server which uses the Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) or something similar. Performance takes a serious penalty as you've seen. Consider staging data using an ETL process if you routinely need to join data between multiple servers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Now i know the direction i have to start first :P

Answer (score 6):

If you're joining tables between two separate Servers, the optimizer is out of the picture.   It no longer has the information it needs to make queries fast

- What indexes are available
- How big are the respective tables?
- What is the distribution of values like on the join columns?

With remote joins, the optimizer knows only the column names and types.    And the server from which you're running the query may have to send an entire table over the wire to allow the proper join logic.

Comment: Does it mean no way to optimize it? I'm not good in English so i might misunderstand your post. I'm really sorry about this. But thank you so much for your great answer.

Comment: @user3386894  There are ways to "optimize" it in the sense of making it run as fast as possible under its current constraints.   But it will never run anywhere close to as fast as if it were local, even with statistics.    Every time you do join, the servers must transmit loads of data back and forth over the wire.   As a general strategy, you might want to try copying subsets of data from the remote server to temporary tables on your local server, and then doing your join local entirely locally:  there's no substitute for experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that user doesn't have enough privileges on the remote server to see the statistical information.

To solve this, you can either upgrade to SQL Server 2012 SP1 (for remote server) or give the user enough privileges: "the user must own the table or be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role on the linkedserver."

More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175129.aspx

And here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/695640/dbcc-show-stati-stics-requires-elevated-priviledges

And here:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2010/11/22/linked-servers-permissions-and-distributed-query-performance.aspx